# Android: ActionBar layout not centering

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

In my action bar, I want the icon and title text to be centered horizontally. Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

The action bar is using a RelativeLayout. The icon image and title text are in a LinearLayout which has android:layout_centerHorizontal="true", but the linear layout is not centering. Here's the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="#dddddd" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleParentLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_orig" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#484848"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightSideParentLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rightButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/addbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Both answers give me this:

[image]

As you can see, the icon and title are still not centered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `LinearLayout` as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleParentLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_orig" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#484848"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/addbutton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you replace your layout with this layout?

Comment: Yes. It does not center the title layout.

Answer (score 0):

in java code use this for `android-version` **3.0 to upper**

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
```

xml file `custom_actionbar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#dddddd">

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleParentLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_orig" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#484848"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/addbutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT :** Screenshot from Samsung tab2

[image]

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: Well, I'm using getSupportActionBar(), because we are supporting 2.2 and up.

Comment: i have used `getSupportActionBar()` too with no issue everything is fine